# Validar controles en vistas ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery

Que es lo mas recomendable para validar controles en las vistas(ASP.NET MVC) controles me refiero a textbox, combobox, etc. En los textbox ingresar letras, numeros, tamaños de textos eso creo se hacer por html, que seria recomendable javascript, jquery?

> **Nota**: Validar del lado del cliente.

Answer (score 2):

Si usas `MVC`, puedes aprovechar las ventajas de `MVC` y crear `MODELS` con `DataAnnotations`

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Así tus clases quedarían:

```
public class Movie {
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [StringLength(5)]
    public string Rating { get; set; }
}
```

como el ejemplo anterior, y agregando los `DataAnnotations` no hay necesidad de que valides o uses algo mas en `javascript`, ya que al generar la vista (basándote en un modelo con  `DataAnnotations`) las validaciones se generaran automáticamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La vista quedaría algo así, basandome en los ejemplo de microsoft:

```
    @model MvcMovie.Models.Movie

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Movie</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Genre)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rating)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rating)
</div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Puedes ver mas información en la liga: [Adding Validation to the Model](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model)

Answer (score 1):

Amigo si vas a hacerlo con jquery o javascript no necesitas las validaciones de requerido del MVC. puedes utilizar jquery para los campos requeridos y para las validaciones de longitud de los campos. también existen funciones ya listas que te validan si es numerico o text con expresiones regulares. puedes visitar [jquery](https://jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Cuando las validaciones se pueden hacer por HTML las hago asi. Y cuando no están las que necesito uso Jquery y JqueryValidate.
Es mucho mas fácil que JavaScript, maneja los problemas de compatibilidad y permite realizar muchos tipos de verificación y emitir mensajes de error.

https://jqueryvalidation.org/